# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid - RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)

Tags: asp.net, image, rotation

Okay, I have this script, at the moment the image URL is correct as it loads using the link. But I'm getting the error which is shown in the subject in this post.

Here is the full error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parameter is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

Source Error: 


Line 33:        {
Line 34:            //Rotate clockwise
Line 35:            img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
Line 36:        } else if (rotate_dir == "anticlockwise")
Line 37:        {

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\nightclub_photography\net\rotate_script.aspx    Line: 35 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType) +618911
   ASP.nightclub_photography_net_rotate_script_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\nightclub_photography\net\rotate_script.aspx:35
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5472; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459
```

Here is the code. It all works fine apart from rotating the image.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

    <script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
        string urlStart = @"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/nightclub_photography/data/images/";

        //Rotation direction
        string rotate_dir = Request.QueryString["dir"];

        //Image locations
        string str = Request.QueryString["t"];
        string[] locs = str.Split(',');

        foreach (string item in locs)
        {
            string url = urlStart + item;

            Response.Write(url+"<br />");

            //create an image object from the image in that path
            System.Drawing.Image tmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(url);
            System.Drawing.Image img = tmp;

            tmp.Dispose();

            //Rotate the image in memory
        if (rotate_dir == "clockwise")
        {
            //Rotate clockwise
            img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        } else if (rotate_dir == "anticlockwise")
        {
            //Rotate anti-clockwise
            img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
        }

        //Delete the file so the new image can be saved
        System.IO.File.Delete(url);

        //save the image to the file
        img.Save(url);

        //release image file
        img.Dispose();
    }
}
</script>
```

If I was to remove the code below the Response.Write, the script will product the following, which is evidence that the URL's are correct.

```
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/nightclub_photography/data/images/13082013/0/1016158_560614047310285_366565184_n.jpg
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/nightclub_photography/data/images/13082013/0/431824_542683245770032_1870555927_n.jpg
```

Comment: Come one guys, someone must know!